# Does Ryu have an official surname?

Tags: street-fighter-series

I searched for Ryu's lastname and found that it is "Hoshi", but somehow I get the feeling this is only used in the "crappy" movie [Street Fighter](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111301/). Here are the sources I have found so far: [Wikia](http://streetfighter.wikia.com/wiki/Ryu), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryu_(Street_Fighter)). The name is always listed under Action Movie or Live Action.

Is Hoshi his "real" name as used by Capcom in the official Street Fighter Series? Perhaps Ryu has no lastname and Hoshi is only used for the movie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hoshi is the name used for Live Action movie adaptations. No "actual" surname has been released. His full name is just Ryu.

Comment: Additionally and non-canon: In the fan short film "Street Fighter: Legacy", he's named "Takashi". This is both a reference to his designer 武神 隆 (Nishiyama Takashi) *and* a small pun for people knowing Japanese: The name would be written "隆 隆" (Takashi Ryuu), using the exact same *Kanji* twice but different spellings thereof.

Comment: Thanks for the comment :) I didn't know that!!!

Answer (score -2):

I tired why you are commenting and trying to post and retire. Ryu is a Street Fighter character owned by Capcom, but don't canon this non-canon name Hoshi with Capcom's Street Fighter franchise. Ryu has no full/real name Ryu Hoshi and Hoshi is only used for the movie. To be canonical to the franchise until next Street Fighter game Street Fighter 6, but in the movie. Hoshi is canon only to the Ryu's appearance in the Street Fighter movies because Ryu's full name isn't Ryu. Ryu's full name have been into Ryu Hoshi. Until Street Fighter III. Ken got a full name, under the name Ken Masters

Comment: I can't make sense of what you are trying to say.  You have too much repetition going on I feel.